# I can't access my closure function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get to call sayIt function from my talk event. I have battled with this through the night.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


   var sayIt = (function() {
        alert("I can now say something.");
    })();


    $("#talk").blur(function(){

       sayIt(); //<-- Uncaught TypeError: sayIt is not a function
    });

});
```

Comment: it's easily accessible are sure it's not working

Comment: try it yourself. I am using the chrome browser. I don't know if it's about the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sayIt` is not a `function` because you declared the function as a self invoking function and `sayIt` just stores the value returned by it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    var sayIt = function() {
        alert("I can now say something.");
    };

    sayIt(); // it you want to call it once

    $("#talk").blur(function(){

       sayIt(); //<-- Uncaught TypeError: sayIt is not a function
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using self invocation function in `sayIt` so it will execute independently on page load and alert the text. But you need to alert when element with id `talk` is blurred. So, remove that function closure and it works as expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   var sayIt = function() {
        alert("I can now say something.");
    };
    $("#talk").blur(function(){
       sayIt();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='talk' />
```

Answer (score 2):

The key to your question is self invoke function. When you put (); after function declaration end it means function will call itself. Change you function as-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // declaration of function //
   var sayIt = (function() {
    alert("I can now say something.");
   });

    $("#talk").blur(function(){
       sayIt(); //this will work fine
    });

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

sayIt is not a function in this case. It's a self invoking function.

You need to change the code for sayIt to:

```
var sayIt = function () {
  alert("I can now ay something.");
}
```

Only then you can invoke sayIt from blur event.

Answer (score 0):

You are using self invocation function it's call automatically. So if you need to call this function you should remove () from your code so code looks like -

```
var sayIt = function() {
    alert("I can now say something.");
});
```

But if you want to call with () so you need to use clouser strategy like -

```
var sayIt = (function() {

    return function () {
        alert("I can now say something.");
    };
})();
```